# Salesforce Bulk API Lock Issue?

Tags: salesforce, bulkupdate

I'm trying to mass update child__c object linked to parent__c object using Salesforce Bulk-API. I will not modify any relations, so in my opinion there is no need to lock parent__c object.

I do not know the parent__c.id, so I cannot order by the parent key to avoid "object already locked" issues.

Will Salesforce allow me to do the mass update or how am I supposed to upload the data in an efficient way?

Comment: Is the relationship master-detail?

Comment: Actually I have 2 cases: one with lookup relationship and one with master-detail relationship.